# NSTask, NSPipe - Can't concatenate the returned string

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstask

In my Mac OS app I have NSTask calling a Python script, which then returns *"connected"* via NSPipe. I then read the data in my Obj-C class, and put it in a string:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSData *readData;

while ((readData = [readHandle availableData])
       && [readData length]) {
    [data appendData: readData];
}

NSString *aString;
aString = [[NSString alloc]
                  initWithData: data
                  encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"append%@me",aString);
```

Later when I try to concatenate the output with another string, I can't - it prints on another line:

```
appendconnected
me
```

And also, I can't test the string with:

```
if ([string isEqualToString:@"connected"]) {
    NSLog(@"yes");
} else {
    NSLog(@"no");
}
```

it shows that they are not equal, although they are!

Why is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There be a newline in the stream.

How are you printing the data on the python side?

If you are using `print "connected"`, it'll output a newline, too.

Note that *not* outputting a newline may cause the data to not be read until the pipe is closed (or more data is written) as the system may buffer things for a bit.

Comment: You're right, I tested it with: `if ([strippedString isEqualToString:@"connected\n"])` , it is there. I'll remove it.  Sounds like there is no good reason to NOT send the /n from Python. (unless I could "force" close the pipe?)